# Is it possible to access deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, deleted-questions, privileges

I was just writing a question about another post, and as just I finished my question and wanted to add a link to the other question. However, when I tried to access it, I found out that that question had just been removed. It was a matter of seconds and still, my question would have not made as much sense without that one, as it served as an example, so in this case:

Is it possible to still view posts that have been deleted from their authors?

Comment: @Machavity the OP is not asking for his own deleted questions. See [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337017/what-happens-if-a-user-is-asking-for-a-bad-practice) for the real purpose.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate with more details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117892/how-do-you-view-deleted-questions

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you have >10k reputation, you will be able to [view deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) if you have a link to them. You can also *search* for your own deleted posts, but not for other user's deleted posts.

If you have less than 10k reputation, you can only view your *own* deleted posts *if you have a link*; posts which were deleted in the last 60 days can be viewed from your profile after clicking the 'Deleted recent answers/questions' link in the 'Answers' or 'Questions' page in your profile respectively.

Three years later, I found a [workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518) that allows one to access their deleted posts (even without having 10k reputation) **provided they were voted on**. You can find those via the reputation history, the link contains more details.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you find your deleted question links with the Stack Exchange Data Explorer ?

Comment: Nope. The `PostsWithDeleted` table is stripped from most information, including who the author of the post was: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/859789/deleted-posts-for-which-the-owner-is-known

Comment: That kinda sucks. It'd have been interesting to look back at my deleted questions from years ago

Comment: @anearwig if it was you who deleted them, you can still see them on your profile's "Activity - votes - deletion" page.

Comment: @WillNess Hi, I deleted my own question 2 days back. I did not find it in "Activity - votes - deletion" page (?tab=votes&sort=deletion)

Comment: @firstpostcommenter It's Activity ⇾ Questions ⇾ link at the bottom of the page "recently deleted questions". Similar for Answers. But it should still show in the other view, because you "voted to delete" it.

Comment: you can also SO-search for "user:me deleted:1".

Comment: sorry, this was directed at @firstpostcommenter. but according to this answer, you need to have 10K reputation for that, which you don't currently have. or maybe this restriction was lifted since then, for the self-searches? do tell.

Comment: @WillNess It's not lifted. The search for "deleted:1" is ignored for "mortals" :)

Comment: @firstpostcommenter I now realize I discovered a workaround a while ago, which might be helpful to you. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

The ability to [view deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) is earned at 10k reputation. Without this privilege, it's not possible to view deleted questions or answers (except your own posts).

However, you can check if the post has been [archived by Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) or [cached by Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en).

Answer (score 10):

As the commenter @Scratte notes, a user's own deleted posts can be found under their profile.

i.e. For deleted questions go to your profile > *Questions* > Scroll to the bottom > Select *recently deleted questions*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try check your questions via google cache, it is easy to do by https://cachearchive.com website. Or try to open it in https://archive.org