# What happens if a user is asking for a bad practice?

Tags: discussion

I am aware that there are good and bad practices and that the good ones should *always* be followed, but what happens when a user is asking for something that is not considered a good practice?

I have seen by now, in many questions, that others are trying to bring the askers down and make them follow good practices, instead of really answering the questions. I can provide a real [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283738/c-sharp-goto-statement-real-life-example) (question is deleted; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJykR.png)) where somebody asked about an example of the use of `goto` instruction in an OOP language; it didn't get an answer which actually provided an example, but comments as answers about how bad it is to use `goto`.

Shouldn't be people encouraged to answer the question instead of saying that this is not *how it should be done*?

Comment: This particular case looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where Y = *I want to use `goto`* and the OP has no idea of X at all.

Comment: Just link to [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/292/) and call it good :P

Comment: @gnat it indeed seems a duplicate of that question, but I don't find it as holding an answer too.

Comment: @Glorfindel it may  be just a half of the XY problem since he knows about other uses of goto, and that he should not be using it, but he is supposed to write about it for school

Comment: @meJustAndrew and that's why Stack isn't good for all homework assigments. We are meant to be a high level repo of knowledge about coding. It makes sense, if you keep that goal in mind, to not help the user load the shotgun pointed at his feet. I sympathize that this must suck when yout assigment is to do it a certain way though...

Comment: @Patrice it is not only about homework, it can be at a job too, if a huge project has been developed with a bad architecture , or have some bad practices, but it's legacy code, so you must follow the rules in that project, (I know this seems isolate, but it can and actually happens to some people) then asking about a solution which uses bad practices becomes a must...

Comment: @meJustAndrew well that's a different game. You can get a solution for the Y of an XY problem. You just need to explain properly(and more than "my teacher told me to use a goto"). If you come with a real architectural constraint that makes sense, explain it in the question, i've seen XY problems where the Y answer was given. You just need a good justification

Comment: Last week I saw someone on the street flapping their arms like a bird.  As I walked by, he said "Hey, why am I not flying? I need to get to NYC ASAP!"  I felt sorry for him, so I went to the Greyhound station and bought him a ticket.  I went back and gave it to the guy, explaining he could get to NYC faster by riding the bus.  He then proceeded to complain that I hadn't provided him a means to generate enough lift with his arms that he could fly himself.  I then proceeded to beat him to death with a park bench.  Why do all these people want to be beaten to death with a park bench?