# Was it necessary to delete this (rightly) closed question so quickly?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Earlier today I came across [this question (10k only)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40359284/2751851). Around an hour after being posted, it was rightly closed for being opinion-based and objectively unanswerable, as the issue boils down to syntactical taste. Shortly after that, I interacted with the question by leaving a few comments (see the "full disclosure" paragraph below). I have just noticed that, around two hours after that (and three hours after the question was posted), the question was deleted. I find that surprising, given that, even though the question was correctly closed, there seems to be nothing so dreadful about it that would make its deletion urgent, and given the negative score it would in all likelihood be deleted automatically in a few days. While I don't think the question is salvageable, and so there is no reason to object to deletion as far as content goes, it was seemingly deleted before the OP had even the opportunity to read and react to the comments (the "last seen" line in the OP's profile currently says "8 hours ago", that is, roughly within an hour of the time the question was posted), which, I believe, makes for a somewhat unnecessarily abrasive resolution.

**Full disclosure:** my interaction with the question consisted in a comment to the OP addressing an issue related to the subject matter of the question (this comment was explicitly not an attempt to answer the question, given that it is unanswerable) and an opinionated comment questioning the need for the quickly accumulating downvotes the question was attracting. This latter comment led to a brief and friendly meta-discussion with another user.

---

P.S.: This question is not a duplicate of [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions). Suppose no one had addressed the subject matter in any way through the comments, but only explained to the OP why their question was unanswerable. My concerns would still apply.

Comment: I personally tend to delete POB questions quickly to hinder getting collection of opinions in comments, and hence encouraging them. Similar for questions asking for 3rd party resource.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is one possible good reason to do so (even though in the specific case of this question the comments about the subject matter were pretty sensible in terms of sticking to the non-opinion based bits within the POB question).

Comment: Do you think they'd be *happier* if it were left open longer so it could gather even more downvotes?

Comment: @AndrewMedico Well, at -8 score that horse had already left the barn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) "Don't ever answer an off-topic question, not via chat, comments, or any other way. It is even dangerous to say: go here, Google for that, because next time, they will do the exact same and eventually get what they want."

Comment: @gnat I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. Suppose no one had addressed the subject matter in any way through the comments, but only explained to the OP why his question was unanswerable. My concerns would still apply.

Comment: (@gnat I also happen to believe that, while the principle you quote applies to a large majority of the off-topic questions posted here on a daily basis, sometimes there are shades of grey, and occasionally it is a reasonable judgment call to guess that the asker is not e.g. a help vampire. In any case, that is a discussion quite independent from this question.)

Comment: @CodeCaster Of course, just because the community often handles that first kind of off topic question incorrectly doesn't mean we should start handling the second type of off topic question incorrectly, it means we should strive to handle that first type of off topic question correctly.

Comment: @Servy of course I agree that off-topic questions should be deleted, because they add no value whatsoever to the site. I applaud Roomba's work, and I'm not saying this question shouldn't have been deleted. It's just pretty annoying that deletion appears to be completely arbitrary: it just depends on who happens to read a question, and what mood they're in. It's not consistent.

Comment: @CodeCaster Of course, and I share your irritation, I just want to make sure you (and relevantly, other readers of your comment) channel that frustration into working harder to *appropriately* handle off topic questions, rather than reversing the efforts of what few questions actually get appropriately handled in the name of "fairness".

Comment: @CodeCaster Of course deletion appears to be arbitrary. There is not enough close votes and delete votes to get rid of all. So people delete something they stumbled upon. That does not mean they would not delete some other questions too.

Comment: The only issue in this case is that people decided to down vote question into oblivion. And it didn't deserved that to happen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> While I don't think the question is salvageable, and so there is no reason to object to deletion as far as content goes,  ...

You've hit on two points that I usually fall back on when looking at deleted posts:

- Is it salvageable?
- Is there something in the answers section worth saving?

You state that you don't think the question is salvageable, and I agree; there's no amount of editing that can save that particular question and bring it on topic.  There's also nothing in the question worth saving; no answers exist on it that would merit an undeletion vote.

> ...[I]t was seemingly deleted even before the OP had even the opportunity to read and react to the comments (the "last seen" line in the OP's profile currently says "8 hours ago", that is, roughly within an hour of the time the question was posted), which, I believe, makes for a somewhat unnecessarily abrasive resolution.

The OP [has the ability to see their own deleted posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337016/1079354) for a limited time, so the fact that they won't be able to see it is lessened.

While I do feel some sympathy in this context - the OP had their question nuked from orbit before they could blink - the fact remains that the question *needed* to be removed.  The only hope we can have now is that this doesn't instantly cause them to rage-quit without at least reading into the context as to *why* it was removed...

Comment: I generally agree. "The only hope we can have now is that this doesn't instantly cause them to rage-quit without at least reading into the context as to why it was removed" -- that is precisely my concern. I can picture the OP coming back to the site at the end of the day, only to find (perhaps with some difficulty) a deleted question and no one to talk about why it was deleted.

Comment: @duplode: I too don't want that to happen to the OP, but it seldom happens on the first occurrence.  Any OP that comes to Meta looking for guidance then would be an OP worth guiding.

Comment: *before they could blink*.... I typically call a one-hour blink a "nap" :P.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan:. Not everyone is in the same time zone.  They may actually be asleep then.

Comment: @Makoto, sure, but why are they asking a question, to which they apparently want an answer, then toddling off to bed? When I ask a question, it's because I've just spent an hour or twenty researching the thing, trying different things out, asking everyone within earshot (of a megaphone), and I really want to know the answer. I'm going to watch that answer like a cat watching a laser pointer. I don't think it's unreasonable to ask posters to at least watch it like a sloth watches a tasty leaf...

Comment: @Makoto asking question on SO and immediately leaving for a day is bad idea - so maybe OP will learn that lesson too and stick around for at least 10-15 minutes to make sure post understood by community (and correct quickly when needed). Generally questions that are left untouched for 1-2 hours will not get any attention by answrers...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: They may not go to sleep, but it was a convenient example.  There may be any number of reasons that a person is pulled from watching their question.  It's unfair to assume they're watching the question like a hawk.

Comment: I see it as the flipside to the other wrong thing that often happens: people thinking they're asking for support and want answers ASAP. We answer things at our own leisure, there are no real deadlines to speak of when it comes to managing content here. It has to be done right, not quick. In that respect... I kind of side with exceptionally fast deletions giving off a wrong signal.