# Is it possible to access my own deleted questions?

Tags: support, privileges

This [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337016/11528241) gives some steps to view my own deleted questions.

1. profile
2. clicking the 'Deleted recent answers/questions' link in the 'Answers' resp

I cannot find Any item contains "Deleted ..." in the profile.

whay does "resp" mean?

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have any recent deleted posts, this is probably the reason you cannot find any items in that section. You can comment under that post and ask the OP

Comment: I think it must mean respectively, so 'answers or questions as relevant'. It's not a form I'm familiar with either.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/56802412) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/56623355) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/56546820) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/56544557) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/56311891) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/56227754))