# Answer removed, makes my referring answer incomplete

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Last year I wrote this answer to a question about *Read the Docs*:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131151/2485966

The answer ends with a note about self-hosting. I never bothered to provide a detailed explanation; I assumed a link to this related question would be sufficient:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130181/how-to-download-the-docs-as-pdf

Unfortunately, that question has been "removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation." Today somebody made me aware of this, and at the same time asked a question about my note that I was hoping to find an answer for under the deleted question.

(In case you are wondering: no, I don't remember the reasoning I followed when writing that particular part of my answer in 2018. If I would have that kind of a long-term memory, then I probably wouldn't feel the need to be an active member of SO.)

According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337014/is-it-possible-to-access-deleted-questions), users with 10k reputation can view deleted posts. Anybody willing to help me out?

Note: yes, I tried the wayback machine (archive.org), but found no history for this question.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3f39a67c18ae1227906bb28d6d616bdf

Comment: The linked question got "roomba'd" due to inactivity (no comments/answers after a certain period of time). So, not a real mod decision. What do you need from that question?

Comment: The question was automatically deleted because it didn't have an answer. I'm not sure what value/information you wanted add with that link.

Comment: @BDL It looks like the relevant part is in the comments where someone points out that PDF generation isn't possible because of something they changed when hosting it themselves. OP, I think it's fine for you to just say that this happens. You don't need to prove it with a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of the deleted question. The question was automatically deleted because it didn't get upvotes and answers in a certain period of time. Imho, the question didn't provide any value that can be used anyway.

[image]